# MVC Identity User in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I have linked my members table with  Application user by foreign key as can be found in the Model

```
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

In Razor View I want to be able to retrieve User details eg

```
@Model.User.FirstName
```

But I get

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Not sure what is missing

Comment: You should declare `public ApplicationUser User` `virtual`, i.e. `public virtual ApplicationUser User`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make your UserId->User relation virtual. So:

```
public int? UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Adding the `virtual` keyword to the declaration of `User` means it will be "Lazy Loaded" which in really short terms means that as soon as you refer to the `User` object, it loads the data from the database.

For more information, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_1